# Continue maven build on test case failure but, fail at end if there are test failures

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I need help on maven goal execution. My use-case is to execute the verify/package goal even if test phase is failing as I need to generate cucumber report after test phase.

**What I tried**-
1- Maven fail-safe plugin-- Being specific for integration test goal, its not useful for me. this is failing on test phase failure.
2- Maven surefire plugin--This is working if I set 'testFailureIgnore' to true but build is SUCCESS even after test phase failure. I want build to fail at the end in case of test phase failure, so I tried below 3rd option-
3- Use fail at end flag-- This seems to be working for multi module projects only whereas I dont have such project structure.

Comment: please add some code and stacktrace to identify the problem

Comment: Its maven pom and project building issue. sorry but I dont think any code snippet is required for this.